# android studio 'waiting for all target devices to come online' and Black AVD error

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

[image]

[image]

My avd doesn't work!
At first time run project is add text 'there is 0 error' but
even that text the avd still BLACK.

I have reinstall SDK,avd delete,Wipe data,etc

Comment: Have you installed any other emulator like memu, noxPlayer etc?

Comment: Did you try holding the virtual power button in the floaty box next to the emulator? You have to manually power it on after the first installation

Comment: @user11113880 nope... i didn't installed......

Comment: @hack5 try to push the power button.but there's no change the emulator's black window.

Comment: @A1 TT did you hold down the button or just tap?

Comment: @Hack5 yeah,,, just click the power bottom,or click the pad anywhere but have this error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))'

Answer (score 8):

Try to cold boot from AVD Manager:

1. Open AVD Manager

   [image: Open AVD Manager]
2. Select "Cold Boot Now" from the dropdown menu

   [image: Select cold boot now from dropdown menu]