# How to fix 'Waiting for Target Device to Come Online'?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I pressed *Run 'app'* and my android studio says "Waiting for Target Device to Come Online…". How do I fix this?

Comment: what is the version of android studio that you are using?

Comment: @dakshbhardwaj its android studio 2021.2.1

Comment: That's too old can you try updating the android studio , new update have features like wireless debugging

Comment: @dakshbhardwaj What do you mean that's too old? I have the latest (Android Studio 2021.2.1 patch 1) and yes it has wireless debugging. I just made this question for people using emulator to debug their app. Some times I just like using an emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Android Studio 4.x.**
*First stop the app if is trying to start by clicking* **Stop 'app'**
Then proceed ending the task **qemu-system-x86_64.exe**

> Task Manager -> Find qemu-system-x86_64.exe (It's Usually under Android Studio Application) -> End Process

**For Android Studio 3.x.**
*There Are two possible fixes*

1. By Stoping the emulator:

> Tools -> AVD Manager -> Right-Click on the emulator -> **Stop**

2. By wiping the data:

> Tools -> AVD Manager -> Right-Click on the emulator -> **Wipe Data**

If Nothing from the above fixed the problem restart computer and if the problem ensists try reinstalling the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The two fixes in the other answer didn't work for me. But I made a duplicate of the misbehaving emulator in Device Manager and this worked. I am now able to delete the original emulator and rename the copy.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343011/android-studio-waiting-for-all-target-devices-to-come-online-and-black-avd-err) was the quickest fix I found. In summary: Open the AVD Manager and select "Cold Boot Now" from the device's popup menu. Once the device has started, you should be able to run your app on it.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable solution I've found is to go into the Task Manager, look in the "Background processes" list for `adb.exe`, and kill it. Android Studio will then restart the daemon that it uses for the emulator and everything works thereafter.